# Concatenar soma de número a uma string

Tags: javascript, string

Quero concatenar uma soma de um numero a uma *string* em JavaScript e tive de recorrer a uma variável auxiliar.

O que fiz primeiro (exemplo incorrecto):

```
for (var i; i < x; i++)
  h = "texto" + x+1 + ".txt";
```

Depois:

```
 for (var i; i < x; i++){
         var a = i+1;
         h = "texto" + a + ".txt"; 
 }
```

Alguma solução para eu evitar aquela variável auxiliar?

Nota: Este não é o código com que estou a trabalhar no momento é só para exemplificar o meu problema. A solução de trocar `i++` por `++i`, não se aplica no meu caso.

Comment: Já tentou isto? `"texto" + (x+1) + ".txt"`

Comment: Não --', obrigado bigown

Comment: Nas duas versões estás a usar o `x` de maneira diferente. Podes explicar melhor o papel do `x` na pergunta?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplesmente por que há um erro de logica na primeira versão. Onde você está fazendo `x + 1`, e na segunda versão `i + 1`. Acredito que o que você queira seja `i + 1`. Também a um problema de precedente de operadores, o que pode ser resolvido circulando o calculo com parenteses `(i+1)`, fazendo com que ele seja executado antes da concatenação. Além do problema de não estar adicionando valor inicial a `i` no `for`: `for (var i = 0; i < x; i++)`, que aqui para mim também fez com que não funcionasse.

Segue o exemplo 1 corrigido (Verifica a saída no console de seu navegador(F12), após mandar executar o snippet):

```js
var x = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++){
  var h = "texto" + (i+1) + ".txt";
  console.log(h);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pra mim nenhum dos dois funcionam, o problema está na declaração do `for`:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let h = "texto" + i + 1 + ".txt";
  console.log(h);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/LoopName.js).