# Variável de jQuery para URL

Tags: php, jquery

É o seguinte, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$('body').on("click", ".delete", function() {
   $('#1').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(0).text());
});
```

Que vai buscar o `id` de uma linha de uma tabela correspondente linha clicada e eu queria pegar nesse valor e colocá-lo no URL assim:

```
window.location('iframes/clientes_apagar.php?cliente_id="Aqui"')
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Concatenar soma de número a uma string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76829/concatenar-soma-de-n%c3%bamero-a-uma-string)

Comment: Afinal nao deu pelo menos da forma que eu tentei

Comment: Altere `window.location('iframes/clientes_apagar.php?cliente_id="Aqui"')` para `window.location.href = 'iframes/clientes_apagar.php?cliente_id="Aqui"';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var id_ = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().text().trim();
```

Em seguida, concatenar esse valor no `window.location`:

```
window.location('iframes/clientes_apagar.php?cliente_id="'+id_+'"');
```

Exemplo:

```js
$('body').on("click", ".delete", function() {
   var id_ = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().text().trim();
    $('#1').val(id_);
    // window.location('iframes/clientes_apagar.php?cliente_id="'+id_+'"');
    alert(id_); // apenas para visualização
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         id 1
      </td>
      <td>
         <a class="delete" href="#">Exibir id da linha</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         id 2
      </td>
      <td>
         <a class="delete" href="#">Exibir id da linha</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nao respondeu mas ajudou Obrigado!!

Comment: @Shider fico contente q tenha ajudado. Obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado eu e desculpe pelo tempo que perdeu!!

Comment: @Shider Bom dia amigo! Qual seria a resposta correta para eu poder ajustar?

Comment: Ja consegui resolver Obrigado!